# How to create .edmx model from access .mdb file?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ms-access

Is it possible to create Entity Data Model (edmx file) from MS Access Database mdb file? If yes then how?
I have tried using Entity Data Model Wizard, but there I could only choose sql databases.

I have website in MVC3 and I need to connect it to dsatabase that is in mdb file.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Just to feed my curiosity; why on earth are you using MS Access? And by the way; I don't think entity framework supports ms access "databases". Port it to sql server instead and forget you ever had this problem :-)

Comment: Although [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132720/entity-framework-with-oledb-connection-am-i-just-plain-nuts) question is a bit dated, I'm tempted to say you can't do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity framework join to ms-access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778825/entity-framework-join-to-ms-access)

Comment: If I had a choice, I would never choose to use ms access "databases". But I get this database with tables and data and now I have to do something with it ...

Comment: SQl Server can could link to the Access file or you could just import all the tables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you are right, I was expecting to have also OLEDB or ODBC listed but there is only SQL Server and SQL Server Compact. Anyway if you are doing serious development at minimum use SQL Express or SQL Compact, both free and probably way better than old MS Access.

With the latest version of SQL Compact (**4**), it runs also in IIS and with Partial Trust so you can use it without any issue with your Hosting Provider, in case you do not want to pay for SQL connectivity.

like you find here: [Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876)

> Enabled to work in the medium or partial trust environments in the web
>   servers, and can be easily deployed along with the website to the
>   third party website hosting service providers.

Comment: It is not really my choice to use MS Access DB. I get mdb file with tables and data and now I have to do something with it.

Comment: then use old good ADO.NET without EF. Or import those tables into SQL Express or Compact.

Comment: @DavidePiras Maybe he could link the tables from the Access database to a copy in SQL Server. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think it should work, right?

Answer (score 4):

MS Access is not supported by EF.