# Use of provider=SQLOLEDB in EF 6 connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqloledb

We have legacy connection strings in use by different sql clients from years past. The connection string has legacy syntax: `"Provider=SQLOLEDB"`.

> `Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=<servername>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;Integrated Security=SSPI`

EF6 uses different SQL client and providers obviously.

So my question is, does there exist a way to configure EF6 to use a provider or connection provider factory that will know how to deal with the provider keyword in the connection string? Currently I'm getting the error message

> Keyword not supported: 'provider'.

I was hoping there might be a way to avoid changing the connection string that doesn't involve a run-time tweak to remove the keyword from the original connection string.

Comment: You could try to parse those connections strings and build a new one, with the proper syntax, from the parts. This is why it's always better to save the server, db name, user, passwords individually instead of a whole connection string.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Entity Framework is a .NET thing. And in ADO.net you are not allowed to use the `SQLOLEDB` provider.

Even though you are actually using the [**OleDbConnection** class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0), and normally OLEDB lets you specify the OLEDB **Provider**, you're just not allowed to here.

The ADO.net **OleDbConnection** class detects if you try to use the `SQLOLEDB` provider, and simply throws an error.

I know that's not (yet) what you're seeing here. What you're seeing here is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1135612/12597):

> The approach you are using to build the EF connection string is correct.
>
> BUT...
>
> The Entity Framework only works with Providers (i.e. SqlClient) that support something called provider services.
>
> The OleDB provider doesn't support 'Provider Services' so you can't use EF with the OleDb (unless you can find a third party OleDb provider with support for EF).
>
> Hope this helps
>
> Alex
>
> (Entity Framework Team, Microsoft)